# App freezes on camera shutter

Tags: ios, memory-management, ios6

I am working on an app using iOS 7. Sometimes I face a problem in iOS 6 device when i open the camera. It freezes on camera shutter. Although I set ARC to YES. I couldn't understand where is the problem?

I used the code for this

```
self.cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.cameraUI.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

self.cameraUI.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
self.cameraUI.navigationBarHidden = YES;

self.cameraUI.showsCameraControls = NO;

self.cameraUI.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
self.cameraUI.delegate = self;

[self.cameraView addSubview:self.cameraUI.view];
```

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you without seeing your code. Or the part that it freezes at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing `addSubview:` to a `UIImagePickerController`'s view. Instead it is recommended to present the `UIImagePickerController` and implement its delegates to get the selected image.

From [Apple docs for How to use `UIImagePickerController`?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html),

> Present the user interface. On iPhone or iPod touch, do this modally (full-screen) by calling the presentViewController:animated:completion: method of the currently active view controller, passing your configured image picker controller as the new view controller.

This is how you can present it from your controller,

```
[viewcontrollerObj presentViewController:self.cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but it is not working, i am using a custom view  as self.cameraView and then use camera on this view.

Comment: As I said i am using a custom view on which camera is added, according to your comment if there is such type of problem, it should be occur every time. but it happens sometimes in ios6 devices, not iOS 7 devices

Comment: @PrachiRajput Reason for that could be increase in memory because the `UIImagePickerController` instances not getting released since their views are retained. My answer is suggesting standard way recommended by Apple.

Comment: Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x17d1aed0> on <TakePicture: 0x17d21f80> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!, this error is coming if i used that line. is there any way to release the memory of UIImagePickerController.